# Is it possible to switch the sound card or motherboard of a Sony Vaio?

Tags: windows-vista, motherboard, sound-card, sony-vaio

I have two Sony VAIO computers and my VGN-FZ240E model's sound card no longer works for some reason. Is there a way I could take the sound card or motherboard from my VGN-NR498D model and transfer it?

Alternatively if there is a way to fix the sound card then any ideas would be welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: You can't.

The reason being: Laptops don't actually have separate sound "cards" that would be exchangeable. The audio interface is integrated into the motherboard, so you can't just take it out and plug it into another machine. Even most desktop PCs now have their audio interface integrated into the motherboard and not as a separate card.

Your laptop has an ExpressCard slot though. That would mean you can buy a sound card for the ExpressCard slot and get your audio working through it again.

Comment: or use a USB sound card

Comment: @Journeyman Geek Hah. Yeah, viable option!

Comment: or working out why its not working. trying a livecd to rule out drivers.. etc